# Java WebSocket сам по себе вызывает @onClose и закрывает соединение

Tags: java, spring, websocket

Доброго времени суток! n-ный час пытаюсь решить проблему. Использую ВебСокеты в приложении. Дело в том, что срабатывает аннотация @onclose без участия пользователя и закрывает соединение.  На сколько я понял за эти несколько часов, проблема начинается  в строке, где я обращаюсь к базе данных.(дальше в коде укажу) в класс я сделал @autowired некого DialogService. Когда дебаггером прохожу по проекту, пробую evaluate dialogservice.fingbyUser1andUser2(u1,u2), получаю ответ, что не может распознать dialogservice. Хотя сам компилятор никаких ошибок не дает. Та и программа не вылетает на этом моменте. Далее даю код..

```
public class DialogSocketManager {

@Autowired
private DialogService dialogService;

@OnOpen
public synchronized void open(Session session) {
    if (getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().getSession() == null) {
        getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().setSession(session);
        System.out.println("Установили сессию для юзера1");

    } else {
        getDialog(session).getUser2Obj().setSession(session);
        System.out.println("Установили сессию для юзера2");

    }
    String u1 = getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().getUsername();
    String u2 = getDialog(session).getUser2Obj().getUsername();
    if (getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().getSession() != null && getDialog(session).getUser2Obj().getSession() != null) {
        ///Вот здесь я и получаю ошибку!
        DialogEntity dialogEntity = dialogService.findByUser1User2(u1, u2);


        if (dialogEntity.getFile() != null) {
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(dialogEntity.getFile().getPath());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                try {
                    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) ois.readObject();
                    try {
                        getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().getSession().getBasicRemote().sendText(dialog.dequeToXmlString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        getDialog(session).getUser2Obj().getSession().getBasicRemote().sendText(dialog.dequeToXmlString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}

 public interface DialogService {

 void save(DialogEntity dialogEntity);

 DialogEntity findByUser1User2(String user1,String user2);
```

}

```
 @Service
public class DialogServiceImpl implements DialogService {

@Autowired
private  DialogDAO dialogDAO;

@Override
public void save(DialogEntity dialogEntity) {
dialogDAO.save(dialogEntity);
```

}

```
@Override
public DialogEntity findByUser1User2(String user1, String user2) {
return dialogDAO.findByUser1AndUser2(user1,user2);
```

}

}

Насколько я разобрался Вебсокет сам вызывает закрытие соединения при наличии ошибки такого рода. Но в чем собственно мой еррор???? Почему Вебсокет закрывает? Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему-то не дает отредактировать комментарий выше, поэтому отдельным ответом.
Боюсь вы не правильно понимаете, как работает Спринг. Для начала Спринг должен найти КУДА ему инжектить бины. А как он найдет, если у вас @Autowired в обычном классе, который Спринг не рассматривает, как свой бин? То есть Спринг стартует, и начинает искать свои бины, то есть аннотации @Component, @Service и так далее. Находит, выпекает из аннотированных классов бины, и начинает их друг в друга инжектить. В вашем случае DialogSocketManager просто не бин, и ничего в него не инжектится.

Comment: Полез в гугл, Вы оказались правы. Добавил @Component к DialogSocketManager, вроде как ошибка та же осталась)

Comment: В общем, значки бинов появились. У меня следующая иерархия наследования есть. есть некий интерфейс DialogDAO extends jpaRepository,    interface Dialog service, DialogServiceImpl impl Dialog Service(помеченный @Service) в нем есть @Autowired dialogDAO, так вот с пометкой компонент,которую Вы дали выскакивает 'Cound not autowire..'' в DialogServiceImpl

Comment: Прям та же? Показывайте текст ошибки. И да, я бы рекомендовал на данном этапе вычистить из кода весь надмозг навроде бесконечных проверок всего на все, и оставить только проблемное место - легче будет искать ошибку. Вообще хорошей практикой было бы вычистить ВЕСЬ метод целиком, и убедится, что соединение не закрывается даже когда вы ничего не делаете. Так же было бы неплохо сделать метод @OnClose
    public void onColse(Session session, CloseReason closeReason){
    } и присмотреться к причине закрытия соединения.

Comment: Что ж из вас все клешнями тянуть надо? " выскакивает 'Cound not autowire..'' в DialogServiceImpl" - ну там же больше написано! Намного больше! Спринг вас любит, он английским языком пишет почему не может инжектнуть бин. Покажите уже что конкретно ему не нравится.

Comment: Да, извините. Пытаюсь параллельно с Вами ее фиксить.
В общем. Я сделал клоузризон. Она мне дает "Normal_Clousure". Бины тоже заинжектились. Я дебагером, когда хожу, то сразу после той строчки "dialogservice.findby..." я попадаю во встроенный клас websocketa(PojoEndpointBase.class) в блок  
catch (InvocationTargetException var9) {
                Throwable cause1 = var9.getCause();
                this.handleOnOpenOrCloseError(session, cause1);  }

Comment: Я прошу прощения, что так долго отвечаю. Стараюсь побольше информации дать. На самом деле, Вы мне очень сильно помогаете

Comment: Вот до чего я дошел. Все-таки строка             DialogEntity dialogEntity = dialogService.findByUser1User2(u1, u2);
дает NullPointerException. Хотя работа программы не прекращается(Это скорее всего вебсокет так устроен). Это я узнал посредством WatchList а в дебаггере. и функции evaluate. Но все же, откуда ексепшн.

Comment: Пардон, но если "dialogService.findByUser1User2(u1, u2); дает NullPointerException", то вот он ваш эксепшен - в исходном коде он не обернут в try...catch, а значит вылетает выше, что предсказуемо закрывает соединение. А вылетает он потому что "Cound not autowire..'' в DialogServiceImpl" То есть в сервис DialogServiceImpl, который вы пытаетесь использовать, что-то там не заинжектилось, и он работает не правильно, кидает исключение, которое не обрабатывает сам, и вот ваш NPE. Который вы тоже не обрабатываете. Как-то так.

Comment: Да) Это ясно) Я ведь и говорю, что  "Cound not autowire..'' -его уже нету. Этот вопрос уже снят. и я отмечу Ваш ответ как верный. Теперь буду открывать топик, почему именно не инжектит

Comment: Вы уже покажите, что идет дальше, за Cound not autowire? Там как бы причина написана должна быть.

Comment: Нету ошибки связанной с Cound not autowire

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу аннотации @Component над DialogSocketManager, он у вас вообще в контекст заходит? Если над классом нет @Component или аналогичной ей, и нигде в конфигурации из этого класса не делается бин (в xml или при помощи аннотации @Bean), то Spring просто не сможет инжектнуть экземпляр DialogService, что приводит к закономерному результату.

Comment: А с чего вдруг она должна быть?)) Если я верно все понимаю, Component это аналогия для Service. Она у меня стоит над классом DialogServiceImpl (implements DialogService). Есть еще контроллер, в который я так же подгружаю Autowired--DialogService.
Там все хорошо инжектит. Или я не верно понял Ваш комментарий !?

Comment: Боюсь вы не правильно понимаете, как работает Спринг.