# Java Bean Не инжектит бины

Tags: java, исключения, null

Здравствуйте! Второй день пытаюсь пофиксить проблему. В проекте пытаюсь достать данные из базы, но вылетает `NullPointerException`. Я думаю, что у меня неправильно инжектит бин `DialogService` в класс и отсюда `NPE`. Подскажите, где именно мой fail.

```
@Component
public class DialogSocketManager {

    @Autowired
    private DialogService dialogService;

     @OnOpen
     public synchronized void open(Session session) {
    if (getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().getSession() == null) {
        getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().setSession(session);
        System.out.println("Установили сессию для юзера1");

    } else {
        getDialog(session).getUser2Obj().setSession(session);
        System.out.println("Установили сессию для юзера2");

    }
    String u1 = getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().getUsername();
    String u2 = getDialog(session).getUser2Obj().getUsername();
    if (getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().getSession() != null && getDialog(session).getUser2Obj().getSession() != null) {
        ///Вот здесь я и получаю ошибку!
        DialogEntity dialogEntity = dialogService.findByUser1User2(u1, u2);


        if (dialogEntity.getFile() != null) {
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(dialogEntity.getFile().getPath());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                try {
                    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) ois.readObject();
                    try {
                               getDialog(session).getUser1Obj().getSession().getBasicRemote().sendText(dialog.dequeToXmlString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        getDialog(session).getUser2Obj().getSession().getBasicRemote().sendText(dialog.dequeToXmlString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

```
public interface DialogService {

      void save(DialogEntity dialogEntity);

      DialogEntity findByUser1User2(String user1,String user2);

}
```

```
@Service
public class DialogServiceImpl implements DialogService {

    @Autowired
    private  DialogDAO dialogDAO;

    @Override
    public void save(DialogEntity dialogEntity) {
        dialogDAO.save(dialogEntity);

    }

    @Override
    public DialogEntity findByUser1User2(String user1, String user2) {
        return dialogDAO.findByUser1AndUser2(user1,user2);

    }

}
```

Вот ссылка на предыдущий топик связанный с этой же проблемой, мало ли..[здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720495/java-websocket-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-onclose-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Вот собственно и ошибка:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.chat.my.socket.DialogSocketManager.open(DialogSocketManager.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase.doOnOpen(PojoEndpointBase.java:65)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointServer.onOpen(PojoEndpointServer.java:64)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:133)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:844)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



    <import resource="appconfig-mvc.xml"/>

<import resource="appconfig-data.xml"/>

<import resource="appconfig-security.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.chat.my.*"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>
```

Comment: Что в конфигах в спринге стоит в context:component-scan ?

Comment: Нужен конфиг спринга.

Comment: В каком пакете лежит DialogServiceImpl?

Comment: com.chat.my.service, а DialogSocketManager в com.chat.my.socket

Comment: Пробовал убрать звездочку? <context:component-scan base-package="com.chat.my"/>

Comment: да, пробовал. Это собственно та проблема, о которой я Вам на почту писал. Копался вчера и понял, что это не в вебсокете ошибка

Comment: Тогда можно будет вечером посмотреть конкретно. Ты нигде не создаешь вручную класс DialogSocketManager?

Comment: Нет. Это как бы сокетовский класс. Он работает чем-то на подобе контроллера, только вместо отлавливания урлов у него метод на открытие, сообщение,закрытие, ошибку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65884/discussion-between---and--).